# Is there a way to make AWS Schema Conversion Tool work with MacOS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-sct

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur for development and the AWS docs mention the schema conversion tool is present for three platforms: Windows, Fedora and Ubuntu. Is there a way to make it work for mac os as well (besides installing a VM)?